# Portable eruv on Shabbos

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If someone one holds a hula hoop on Shabbos, would he be able to carry his own eruv? If actively carrying it is problematic, could he passively carry it attached to his hat?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Are you sure this is Purim Torah and not just an honest question with a funny premise?

Comment: @Scimonster It was a joke shared with friends and my rabbi. Apparently I misunderstood "Purim Torah". My loss.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one may, and kohanim are makpid to do this when they are near graves. In fact, if you wear a key belt on Shabbos, it is already an eiruv and you may carry anything you want (just make sure to clip lechis to each of your legs). It is useful to note that according to some [academic opinions](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1475-5661.00040/abstract), the prohibitions on work are not so strong within an eiruv; according to these, you may even carry an eiruv in the form of a car, which you may drive to shul or anywhere you want.